# Excel VBA: Custom Function not behaving

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on developing a custom function to assist in gathering more detailed information from a data set.  I have excel recognizing the function exists, it allows me to input my parameters but it is giving me a #VALUE! error.

I suspect it may have to do with some of the arrays and how I'm trying to gather the data to be displayed.

I have 2 tables the main data table and a call table which contains the extra data I'm trying to gather.

I'm looking at how many 'slots' each item occupies based on it's start time and duration.  I've attempted to use a Do Until loop to fill an array with the 'slots' the item occupies and to then display that list in the output cell of the function.  Feel free to ignore my comments.

```
 Function SlotsOccupied(Duration, StartTime, Day)


    Dim SlotsUsed() As String
    ReDim SlotsUsed(0 To Duration)  'sets SlotsUsed array size
    Dim StartT(0 To 1)    'sets Array StartT
    Dim StarTarr As Variant
    Dim DurCount as Integer
    Dim SlotCount as Integer
    Dim StartTCount as Integer


                                      'Sets Counts and starting variables
    DurCount = 0
    SlotCount = 0
    StartTCount = StartTime


    StartT(0) = Day                 'sets StartT array values
    StartT(1) = StartTime


    Do Until DurCount = Duration

        StartTarr = Join(StartT, ",")

        Slot = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(StarTarr, Slots.Range("a2:b56"), 2, False)

        SlotsUsed(SlotCount) = Slot

        DurCount = DurCount + 1
        StartTCount = StarTCount + 1
        SlotCount = SlotCount + 1

    Loop

    SlotsOccupied = Join(SlotsUsed, ",")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've not done any coding in a rather long time and I'm feeling the rust on my brain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You never dim your variables durcount, slotcount, or starttcount.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I feel like a numpty for not having done it initially.  I've fixed that now but still getting the value error.  Does the rest of the code look OK?

Comment: Update your original post to include the updated code, please. And have you tried manually iterating through your code? That might help you debug.